# How to select row ranges manually with odsfile?

Tags: odsfile

How can I select multiple, non connected row ranges with odsfile as indicated in the following pseudocode:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Compile with lualatex
\usepackage{odsfile}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\includespread[file=test.ods,range=a2:a10 and c2:c10]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Compile with lualatex
\usepackage{odsfile}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\includespread[file=test.ods,range=a2:a10 and c2:e10]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP speaks of "row ranges" in the question.  However, from the comment to the initial answer provided here, the OP is requesting a more significant refinement.  Namely, the OP would desire to read only select columns from a table block.

Because of the way the `odsfile` package and `tabular` interact, it would appear that, rather than reading one column of data and then reading another column of data, the process is to read the data by row, extracting the desired columns as needed so as to formulate the `tabular` row, and then move to the next row.

As I commented, for row ranges, it works to use multiple invocations of `\includespread`, one for each row range.  For selective (non-inclusive) column ranges, one must get clever with the `rowtemplate` function.  I cannot include a `&` column separator directly in the `rowtemplate` function; however, I do include it by way of `\ampersand`, which is defined as a `&`.

The `pokus.ods` file in the MWE is the sample that comes with the `odsfile` package, found at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/odsfile.

In the MWE, I import a rectangular block from the spreadsheet "List1", from column `a` of row `1` through column `c` of row `3`, but I use `rowtemplate` to only output columns `a` and `c` of each row (ignoring the `b` column).  Then again, I import from row `6`, columns `a` through `c` (but again ignore column `b`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{odsfile}
\newcommand\ampersand{&}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\includespread[file=pokus.ods,sheet=List1,range=a1:c3,rowseparator={\\},
  rowtemplate={\unskip-{1} \ampersand -{3}}] \\
\includespread[sheet=List1,range=a6:c6,rowseparator={\\},
  rowtemplate={\unskip-{1} \ampersand -{3}}] 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

pokus.ods (List1 tab):

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't exactly answer my question. As you can see that in my example the numbers of the rows are the same (2 to 10). So I want to append different columns. Your solutions appends different rows. That's a different problem.

Comment: @student You are right.  I misunderstood.  I will shortly delete my answer unless I can resolve it.

Comment: @student Please see my revision.